# c++ parsing protobuf messages with switch/case (reducing duplicate code)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, code-duplication

I'm trying to build server application program parsing protobuf packets from client.

packet processing codes are like below :

in proto file,

```
package protocol;

message messageA
{
    ...
}

message messageB
{
    ...
}

message messageB
{
    ...
}

...
```

in code file,

```
enum {
    messageTypeA = 1,
    messageTypeB, 
    messageTypeC, 
...
}

void ProcessPacket(int protocolID, char* packetData)
{
    string messageTypeString = "";

    switch(protocolID)
    {
        case messageTypeA : 
            protocol::messageA packet;

            packet.ParseFromArray(packetData, sizeof(padketData));

            messageTypeString = "messageA";

            ...    //kind of logging packet procedure

            break;
        case messageTypeB : 
            protocol::messageB packet;

            packet.ParseFromArray(packetData, sizeof(padketData));

            messageTypeString = "messageB";

            ...    //kind of logging packet procedure

            break;
        case messageTypeC : 
            protocol::messageC packet;

            packet.ParseFromArray(packetData, sizeof(padketData));

            messageTypeString = "messageC";

            ...    //kind of logging packet procedure

            break;
    }

    //using messageTypeString and so on..
}
```

As we can see, when packet kind grows, there are so many duplicated code.

How can I reducing duplicated code?

Is there any way to mapping `protocolID(enum value)`, type of `packet` and `messageTypeString` at once?

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! `sizeof(packetData) == 4` (or possibly 8) - it's the size of the pointer, not the data it points to.

Comment: Well, there's not much you can factor out in the code you show; but then, it's only three lines per case (and I don't see the point of `messageTypeString `  - it seems to carry the same information as `protocolID`). If there's code that could be generalized and reused, it's probably hiding behind `//kind of logging packet procedure`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oops, I made a mistake for `sizeof`. actually, It's kind of psuedo-code, maybe some holes in the code. in my real code, that part doesn't cause problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're right, duplicated parts are in `...//kind of logging packet procedure` parts. I think that part can be moved to function, but I don't know how to.if there are way to mapping enum value and protocol type, (like messageTypeA with protocol::messageA, messageTypeB with messageB, and so on), I can throw only protocolID as a parameter, and code will be short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines, I suppose:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::Message>> protocols = {
  {messageTypeA, std::make_unique<protocol::messageA>()},
  {messageTypeB, std::make_unique<protocol::messageB>()},
  {messageTypeC, std::make_unique<protocol::messageC>()}
};

void ProcessPacket(int protocolID, char* packetData, int packetSize) {
  auto it = protocols.find(protocolID);
  assert(it != protocols.end());
  std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::Message> packet{it->second->New()};
  packet->ParseFromArray(packetData, packetSize);
  std::string messageTypeString = packet->GetTypeName();
  //kind of logging packet procedure goes here
}
```

Hopefully, your "kind of logging procedure" can work in terms of generic `Message`

Comment: It works! initializing map with init list cause compile error, so I initialize it empty and insert data later in initialize methods.

thanks a lot!